# calling executeScript in onUpdated handler (chrome extension)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have this code:

```
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, changes, tab)
    {
     if (changes.status != "complete") return false;
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {code: "alert('Page loaded.');"});
    });
```

It's executes in debugger, but does not works. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this exactly as defined here.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Execute script app",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "persistent":true,
        "page":"background.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
            "matches": ["http://*/*"],
            "js": ["app.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

**background.html**

```
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if(changeInfo && changeInfo.status == "complete"){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "alert('Page loaded.');"});
    }
});
```

**app.js**

```
//well this is just empty since ur not doing anything here
```